# how to use onchange() or onselect() with jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

in view page we have, some radio button, so onclick of radio button, select and option tag will display values using scriplets.

Here is the previous code:

```
pl_selection=is javascript function
hsMap.get("product_line")=getting values from database
```

code for radio button

```
 <input type="radio" name="pl_type" value="pl"  onClick="pl_selection('pl');" 
<% if(pl_type.equals("pl")) { %> checked <% } %>><%=hsMap.get("product_line") %>
```

aLProdline=is the java arraylist.
code for select and option tag:

```
 <% if((pl_type.equals("pl")) || (pl_type.equals(""))) { %>
    <div id="pl_list" style="display:">
    <% } else { %>              
    <div id="pl_list" style="display:none">
    <% } %>
    <select name="prodline" size="8" multiple id="select15" style="width:   250px;">
    <%for(int i=0; i<aLProdline.size();i=i+2){ %> 
    <option value="<%=aLProdline.get(i)%>" <%   if(plx.indexOf((String)aLProdline.get(i))!=-1) { %> selected <% } %>title="   <%=aLProdline.get(i) %> - <%=aLProdline.get(i+1) %>"><%=aLProdline.get(i) %> -     <%=aLProdline.get(i+1) %></option>
    <% }  %>
    <option value="">
    </select>
    </div>
```

now my work is to get the values from scriplets and display using javascript.
here is my problem:
i get the values from attributes, but am having problem in displaying in proper manner means alignment problem.
This is old code and i need to replace with javascript.

Comment: alignment problem like what? Are the select options getting populated?

Comment: in alert msg, it displays value but select and option tag are not working properly.

Comment: you mean the values show up in alert but not on page when `if((pl_type.equals("pl")) || (pl_type.equals("")))` evaluates to true?

Comment: condition are good,if((pl_type.equals("pl")) || (pl_type.equals(""))),if u can, can u provide the alternative way to display values in javascript

Comment: I understand that the conditions are good, my question is are the values getting displayed when the condition is true?

Comment: yes, values are getting displayed.

Comment: Why do you have `<div id="pl_list" style="display:">`? Shouldn't it be `<div id="pl_list" style="display: block">`? A typo? Please change that. Now, what sort of allignments prob u see?

Comment: it is doing nothing.

Comment: the radio button is doing nothing on click right? `onClick="pl_selection('pl');` should be `onclick="pl_selection('pl');`. I mean it's `onclick()` not 'onClick()'

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: and what do u see on that link, `onclick` or `onClick`?? Capital 'C' or small 'c'??? I know how onclick is written, I don't need that w3schools link!!

Comment: Thanks Sudhansu Choudhary for ur help.

Comment: Please share the pl_selection function

Comment: function pl_selection(pl_type_selected)
{
    var prodline_list = document.Form1.prodline
    
    if (pl_type_selected == 'pl'){
    
        pl_list.style.display='';
        a.style.display='none';
        b.style.display='none';
        c.style.display='none';
        d.style.display='none';
        }.....